# I couldn't login my phpMyAdmin account after changing the settings from the config.inc.php file

Tags: phpmyadmin

I changed the settings from the config.inc.php file then I could go to the phpMyAdmin but when I used the corresponding username and password that I changed I received the below error message.

Error:

> mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: why didn't you use the gui to change it?

Comment: I do not know how to use gui zo? What do you mean?

Comment: sorry it was a typo. https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/privileges.html

Comment: Where should I change in order to get access to phpMyAdmin?

Comment: please check the link in my last comment, there is all explained about user management in phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

In your `config.inc.php`, you probably have lines for `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']` but haven't yet created the control user in MySQL. You can comment out the two lines in `config.inc.php` in order to get access to phpMyAdmin, then if you still desire to use the advanced features you can create a control user following [these steps](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#manual-configuration).

Comment: The problem is still not solved although I followed the above

Comment: Did the error message change at all? Are you able to log in with the command line client?

Comment: I used the corresponding username and pw but still same error

Comment: If you're not able to log in through the command line client either, that means the username and password you are trying are not correct. You should ask your database administrator to confirm the correct details, or if you self-host you can reset them: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html